# Use Cauchy's Residue Theorem to solve for $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos \left(e^{-z}\right)}{z^2} dz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function, residue-calculus

I know how to solve for the basic about this.  But in this problem

$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos \left(e^{-z}\right)}{z^2} dz}$,

I don't know how to start.  Can somebody help me or guide me about this? Or just give me a hint.  Thanks.  I would appreciate the help.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives?

Comment: Hey Martin.  Thanks for the comment. I know.  I just don't know how to attack having expression $\cos (e^{-z})$.

Comment: With $f(z) = \cos(e^{-z})$ the integral is equal to $f'(0)$ – can you evaluate that?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't see how it becomes equal to f'(0).  Would you mind show me that?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. If you really know the integral formula for derivatives, you should also know that you wrote *precisely* $f'(0)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not able to figure our Professor Vector.  I just don't know how to involve the complex exponential.  I know integral formula for some but not with the complex exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, recall the following form of Cauchy's integral formula. Let $f$ be a function holomorphic on some neighborhood of unit disk, then
$$f^{(n)}(w)=\frac{n!}{2i\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-w)^{n+1}}d\zeta.$$

The above theorem is sometimes only mentioned for $n=0,$ but it is true more generally. Once you have the above formula, you observe that $f(z)=\cos(e^{-z})$ is holomorphic in the disk, and taking $w=0,$ you obtain
$$f'(0)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz.$$

This is what was mentioned in the comment above. Therefore, you job reduces to finding the derivative $\frac{d}{dz}\vert_{z=0}\cos(e^{-z}),$ which is a straightforward computation using chain-rule.

Comment: Thanks for the answer J.G.  So much help

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using the residue theorem directly, as the headline asks for. I wish to emphazise that I am aware that the calulation is completely analogous, and that I simply show this as an alternative since it appears from the comments and the headline that the asker might be more comfortable with the residue theorem as the starting point here. I urge him however, to think about why these two approaches are equivalent in this case.

Observe that $f(z) = \frac{\cos(e^{-z})}{z^2}$ has a pole of order 2 at $z = 0$ with residue

$$\text{Res}(0) = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dz} z^2 f(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \sin(e^{-z})e^{-z} = \sin(1).$$ By the residue theorem we then have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{\cos(e^{-z})}{z^2} dz = \sin(1) $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fenris.  So much help.  Thank you very much